# trying to execute a dymanic sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

```
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = 'update [EmployeeAttendence] set ['+CONVERT(varchar,2)+
'] ='+Convert(varchar,090000)+
' where EmployeeID='+convert(varchar,1)+
' and [Month]='+convert(varchar,1)
exec   @sql
```

error poped out is ......

> The name 'update [EmployeeAttendence] set [2] =90000 where
>   EmployeeID=1 and [Month]=1' is not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

sometime is so easy you can't even think of.
I just tried it with brackets

```
exec (@sql)
```

and it worked.... ;-)